# Connection keep-alive not working with System.Net.Http.HttpClient on certain hosts

Tags: .net, http, ssl, tcp, dotnet-httpclient

I'm experimenting with the Heroku API using the .NET `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. In particular, I want `keep-alive` to work so that I can send many HTTP requests using one TCP connection and only do one SSL handshake instead of setting up a TCP connection with SSL handshakes per request.

I'm testing against https://api.heroku.com/status which gives a nice HTTP 200, and using Wireshark to monitor TCP traffic.

Google Chrome, ApacheBench (with `-k` flag) and curl all seem to be able to keep a TCP connection open and send multiple requests. HttpClient, not so much. I have also tested HttpClient against other hosts (eg. https://google.com/ and there I only see one SSL handshake/TCP setup. So it seems like it's a bad interaction between HttpClient and the Heroku API.

Here's the code I'm testing with:

```
private static async void TestUrl(string url)
{
    using (var client = GetClient())
    {
        await client.GetAsync(url);
        await client.GetAsync(url);
        await client.GetAsync(url);
        await client.GetAsync(url);
    }
}

private static HttpClient GetClient()
{
    var requestHandler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseCookies = false,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip,
    };

    return new HttpClient(requestHandler);
}
```

I'm also attaching a Wireshark screenshot showing how HttpClient decides to reset (`RST`) the connection as soon as it's done receiving data.

[image: Wireshark screenshot]

Any suggestions for what's going on here?

Comment: What does Fiddler show? If they negotiate HTTP 1.0, then you need an explicit Keep-Alive header.

Comment: @StephenCleary Google Chrome shows HTTP/1.1

Comment: I meant between `HttpClient` and Heroku.

Comment: @StephenCleary When debugging and inspecting stuff, the HttpResponseMessage I get out of HttpClient shows `Version: 1.1`, so I'm assuming that's OK. I've also tested with Fiddler2 - it's HTTP 1.1 and `Connection: keep-alive` is sent alright.

Answer (score 7):

Use *WebRequestHandler* class instead of *HttpClientHandler* and set property [HttpWebRequest.UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.unsafeauthenticatedconnectionsharing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  to True.

Answer (score 0):

Some proxy servers will ignore the keep-alive when doing their authentication.  If I recall correctly it's when the proxy server uses NTLM authentication.

In the past, I've had to add a partial class to "help" some web service proxy classes.

I overrode the GetWebRequest(Uri uri) method with

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest webRequest = 
        (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
webRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Veraion10;  // I know this is strange, but it works
webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;  // This is where the magic lives
return webRequest;
```