# How to reuse HTTP connection across multiple requests?

Tags: c#, http, fiddler, dotnet-httpclient

I'm making an application which constantly scans remote website for any changes.
I'm using `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, but I noticed that it probably doesn't support reusing connection.

Requests are executed one after one, but normally they take about 250 ms to be completed. When I have Fiddler turned on with "Reuse server connections" option on, it drops to as low as 150 ms per request.

I guess I have misconfigured `HttpClient`, but I can't find any information in MSDN reference which would help me to solve the problem.

Comment: May be Http connection pooling is the answer. You can look for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085708/is-http-connection-pooling-possible

Comment: HttpWebRequest is "obsolete (does not compile) in 4.5.2 and later". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190216%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm thinking of HTTP1.0 actually. Looking for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a HttpWebRequest, you would need to set the `KeepAlive` [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx).

HttpClient doesn't appear to offer a similar property, but it probably attempts to use keepalive by default. What are the request and response headers? (HTTP/1.0 only supports keepalive if the server explicitly sends a `Connection: Keep-alive` response header.

[Connection keep-alive not working with System.Net.Http.HttpClient on certain hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894739/connection-keep-alive-not-working-with-system-net-http-httpclient-on-certain-hos) may be related.