# Remove Host header in HttpClient request

Tags: c#, http, fiddler

I'm using the HttpClient class to send some data to specific host. I just want to send a pure header without any additional lines in it like ("Host: http"). So this line is the last to be removed from the header, but I don't know how.

The code:

```
HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, aUrl);
msg.Headers.Clear();
msg.Headers.Remove("Host");
msg.Headers.ExpectContinue = false;
Encoding encoding = ConfiguratorASUST.Instance.Encoding ?? Encoding.GetEncoding(ConfiguratorASUST.ENCODING_DEFAULT);
msg.Content = new StringContent(aStr, encoding);
_client.SendAsync(msg);
```

The result header in Fiddler:

```
POST http://http//localhost.fiddler:60001/POS/POSTELESPIS HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=windows-1251
Host: http
```

This line `Host: http` needs to be removed from the message's header. But how on earth can I do that?! I tried the following:

```
msg.Headers.Clear();
msg.Headers.Remove("Host");
```

To no avail. Actually I also see the header `Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive` being added.

Answer (score 5):

If you carefully inspect your URL, it looks like your it is wrong anyway: `http://http//` - is your host really named `http`, and do you really need two slashes after it? Anyway if you fix that, the `Host` header will carry `localhost.fiddler:60001`.

By removing the Host header, you're essentially downgrading your request to HTTP/1.0.

You can set the HTTP version in the `HttpRequestMessage` as explained in [Set HTTP protocol version in HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097457/set-http-protocol-version-in-httpclient):

```
msg.Version = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

But when using Fiddler, it acts as a proxy, and forwards your request as an HTTP/1.1 request - including the host header again. You can also alter the request in Fiddler. This is explained in [How do I prevent fiddler from insering "Host" HTTP header?](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-do-i-prevent-fiddler-from-insering-host-http-header), but note the bold text, emphasis mine:

> Per the RFC, as a HTTP/1.1 proxy, Fiddler is required to add a Host header.
>
> It's not clear why this is problematic-- **any server that has a problem with this is, by definition, buggy and should be fixed**.
>
> You can remove the header if you'd like (although doing so can cause problems elsewhere). Click Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll to OnBeforeRequest and add the following:
>
> ```
> if (oSession.oRequest.headers.HTTPVersion == "HTTP/1.0")
> {
>     oSession["x-overridehost"] = oSession.host;
>     oSession.oRequest.headers.Remove("Host");
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, CodeCaster, for such a comprehensive answer.

Comment: The matter is that we'll have to work with "non-full-standard" http protocol
Just one more connected question. Could we somehow to eliminate from header line "Connection: Keep-Alive" using standard HttpClient and HttpRequestMessage?

Comment: I think that's off by default. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17894739/connection-keep-alive-not-working-with-system-net-http-httpclient-on-certain-hos. You also must configure Fiddler to not reuse client connections.

Comment: it turned out that "Connection: Keep-Alive" is ON by default. And we have this line in every our POST request header. Page under the link has not helped us to remove it. Thought their should be easy way to achieve this.. but it is not solved yet. Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: No, it is not. How do you determine it is?

Comment: I meant it is ON for HTTP/1.1 which we are using now. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) So we don't set any flags and we have this Keep-Alive mark in header. But want "Connection: Close"

Comment: What I am asking is how you see that that is the case.

Comment: It is solved now.
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
Thanks.